# Scrapy ItemLoader Error while trying to send data to a database

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I'm given a website to scrape, an extra file(dp_data_mgr.py) including a send_data function to import to my spider script and send the scraped data towards a web database. The issue I'm stuck for days is I can't make ItemLoader send the data as for the moment I'm receiving this :
`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "C:\Users\gs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 30, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "C:\Users\gs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "C:\Users\gs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\gs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\gs\scrapy_projects\DynamicPricing\avtogumibg\avtogumibg\spiders\avtogumibg.py", line 88, in parse_specs_page
    misc=params
  File "/Users/gs/scrapy_projects/DynamicPricing/avtogumibg/avtogumibg/spiders\dp_data_mgr.py", line 48, in send_data
    common_keys = data.keys() & misc.keys()
AttributeError: 'ItemLoader' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

`
The dp_data_mgr file is located in my spiders folder. 
How do I need to modify my code to make it work ?

Spider.py:

```
import scrapy
import sys

sys.path.append('/Users/gs/scrapy_projects/DynamicPricing/avtogumibg/avtogumibg/spiders')
from dp_data_mgr import send_data
from scrapy.spiders import Spider

from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.http import Request

from avtogumibg.items import AvtogumiItem


class AvtogumiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'avtogumibg'
    allowed_domains = ['bg.avtogumi.bg']
    start_urls = ['https://bg.avtogumi.bg/oscommerce/']
    BASE_URL = 'https://bg.avtogumi.bg/oscommerce/'


    def parse(self, response):
        brands = response.xpath('//div[@class="brands"]//@href').extract()
        if brands:
            for brand in brands:
                yield Request(url=self.BASE_URL + brand, callback=self.parse_page, dont_filter = True)

    def parse_page(self, response):

        brand = response.xpath('//h4[@class="brand-header"]/span/text()').extract_first()
        listing_url = response.url
        urls = response.xpath('//div[@class="col-xs-12 full-box"]//h4//@href').extract()
        if urls:
            for url in urls:
                yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_specs_page,meta={'brand':brand,'listing_url':listing_url})
        else:
            return

        next_page_url = response.xpath('//div[@class="col-md-12 text-center hidden-sh hidden-xs hidden-sm m-top"]//li/a[@class="next"]/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page_url:
            yield Request(url=self.BASE_URL + next_page_url[0], callback=self.parse_page)

    def parse_specs_page(self, response):

        subj = response.xpath('//div[@class="full br-5 bg-white top-yellow-bd"]')
        l = ItemLoader(item=AvtogumiItem(), selector=subj, response=response)

        l.add_value('url', response.url,)

        l.add_xpath('name', '//div[@class="product-box-desc"]/h4/text()',)
        l.add_xpath('prodId', '//div[@class="product-box-desc"]/p/text()',)

        l.add_xpath('category', './/div[@class="col-sh-6 col-xs-4 col-lg-1"]/p/text()',)

        l.add_value('brand', response.meta.get['brand'],)

        l.add_xpath('sPrice', './/p[@class="price font-bold"]//text()',)

        l.add_xpath('stock', './/div[@class="full m-top product-availability"]//span//text()',)
        l.add_xpath('images', './/div[@class="full-product-box main-product"]//@src',)

        specsTable = {}
        atms_key = subj.xpath('.//div[@class="full m-top product-features"]/div/p/span/text()').extract()[0]
        atms_val = subj.xpath('.//div[@class="full m-top product-features"]/div/p/text()').extract()[0]
        specsTable[atms_key] = atms_val

        speed_key = subj.xpath('.//div[@class="full m-top product-features"]/div/p/span/text()').extract()[1]
        speed_val = subj.xpath('.//div[@class="full m-top product-features"]/div/p/text()').extract()[1]
        specsTable[speed_key] = speed_val

        tyre_type_key = subj.xpath('.//div[@class="full m-top product-features"]/div/p/span/text()').extract()[2]
        tyre_type_val = subj.xpath('.//div[@class="full m-top product-features"]/div/p/text()').extract()[2]
        specsTable[tyre_type_key] = tyre_type_val

        manuf_key = subj.xpath('.//div[@class="full m-top product-features"]/div/p/text()').extract()[3]
        manuf_val = subj.xpath('.//div[@class="full m-top product-features"]/div/p/span/text()').extract()[3]
        specsTable[manuf_key] = manuf_val

        l.add_value('specsTable', specsTable)

        listing_url = response.meta.get['listing_url']

        params = l
        yield l.load_item()
        send_data(access_token='',  # Provided by DP
              site_id='https://bg.avtogumi.bg/oscommerce/',  # Provided by DP
              proxy_ip='No proxy_ip',  # When using a proxy servers provider, they can provide a response header with the IP of the proxy used for this page request
              page_url=response.url,  # The current URL of the product page
              listing_url=listing_url,  # URL of the listing page from where we came to the product page
              misc=params
              )
```

dp_data_mgr.py:

```
def send_data(access_token, site_id, proxy_ip, page_url, listing_url, misc):
# print('Gonna send req to: ', url_service, '    dev_mode: ', dev_mode)
headers = {
    'Dp-Craser-User-Token': access_token,
    'Dp-Craser-Dev-Mode': 'yes' if dev_mode else 'no'
}
data = OrderedDict([
    ('siteId', site_id),
    ('proxyIP', proxy_ip),
    ('urlPage', page_url),
    ('urlRef', listing_url),
])
common_keys = data.keys() & misc.keys()
assert not common_keys, 'You have passed some properties in "misc" that have the same names as the explicit params: ' + ', '.join(common_keys)
data.update(sorted(misc.items()))  # Append all misc items to the end, but sort only them
# print('Req data:\n', json.dumps(data, indent=4), '\n')
try:
    resp = requests.post(url=url_service, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers, verify=False)
    if resp.status_code != 200:
        print('RECEIVED ERROR FROM SERVER:', resp.json())
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print('REQUEST EXCEPTION:', e)


 #===================== Usage example ==========================================

def send_example_request():
    params = dict(
        # Here are some commonly used properties. Populate them whenever possible.
        prodId='3842JfK',  # The product ID (also known as SKU). Must be a string (even if it only contains digits).
        name='The name of product X',
        category='Hardware >> Laptops',  # breadcrumbs
        brand='ASUS',
        eans=['1234567'],  # The expected type is an array of strings. Do NOT assign a string directly, even if the product has exactly one EAN!
        partNums=[],  # The expected type is an array of strings. Do NOT assign a string directly, even if the product has exactly one part number!
        images=['http://example.com/3842JfK/p1.jpg', 'http://example.com/3842JfK/p2.jpg'],  # An array of image URLs. Do NOT assign a string directly, even if the product only has zero or one images!
        stock='Out of stock',  # Other example values are "In stock", "Not available", etc.
        specsTable=[
            {'key': 'Color', 'value': 'Brown'},  # Note that the keys and values will usually be localized (i.e. not necessarily in English)
            {'key': 'Series', 'value': 'X540'},
            {'key': 'CPU', 'value': 'Intel Core i3-5005U'},
            {'key': 'RAM', 'value': '4GB (1x 4096MB) - DDR3, 1600Mhz'},
        ],
        sPrice='1,299.99',  # The raw value as a string. If the product is in promotion, set the promo price here.
        sOldPrice='1,429.99',  # The raw value as a string. If the product is in promotion, this price will often be displayed as scratched.
        # We can also add some custom properties:
        someCustomProperty='abc',
        zzzzz=False
    )
    send_data(access_token='someCode',  # Provided by DP
              site_id=102,  # Provided by DP
              proxy_ip='SomeIP-here',  # When using a proxy servers provider, they can provide a response header with the IP of the proxy used for this page request
              page_url='SomeURL',  # The current URL of the product page
              listing_url='URL-FromWhereWeCameToThisProductPage',  # URL of the listing page from where we came to the product page
              misc=params
              )
```

items.py :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose, Join, TakeFirst

from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class AvtogumiItem(scrapy.Item):


    def make_absolute_url(url, loader_context):
        return loader_context['response'].urljoin(url)

    strip = MapCompose(str.strip)

    url = scrapy.Field(input_processor=strip, output_processor=TakeFirst())
    name = scrapy.Field()
    prodId = scrapy.Field()

    category = scrapy.Field()
    brand = scrapy.Field(input_processor=strip,)

    sPrice = scrapy.Field(input_processor=strip, output_processor=TakeFirst())
    sOldPrice = scrapy.Field(input_processor=strip, output_processor=Join())

    stock = scrapy.Field(input_processor=strip,output_processor=TakeFirst())
    images = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(make_absolute_url), output_processor=TakeFirst())    
    specsTable = scrapy.Field(input_processor=strip,output_processor=TakeFirst())
```

All help would be greatly appreciated as I'm out of any ideas how to fix this. 
Thank you all in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ItemLoader object instead of Item/dict it generates:

```
params = l
yield l.load_item()
```

Should be:

```
params = l.load_item()
yield params
```

Comment: @Stan no worries, happens to the best of us! ItemLoaders and Items are easy to confuse at the beginning.